# Insert form data into two different tables on database through jsp page

Tags: java, html, mysql, database, jsp

i have the bellow code that it doesnt add on database any insert but if i delete the second one  "myStatement.executeUpdate(insert) "  , it takes me the first insert (sqlstring)... how can i run both inserts and save data for both tables ????  To be more specific , i need to take data from users form and save them to database, but here is the point... in checkboxes user can check two and less... so can you help me if the tables and formation of them is right and if its right what can i do in order to take the two values of checkboxes and insert them in one table...

```
 <%@page import="java.sql.*" %> 
    <%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
            <title>create dest code</title>
        </head>
        <body>
             <%


       String id8=request.getParameter("id8");
       String id9=request.getParameter("id9");
       String id10=request.getParameter("id10");
       String ch1=request.getParameter("dest1");

       String empty= "";
       boolean flag=false;
       if (!(id8.equals(empty) | id9.equals(empty) | id10.equals(empty) )) {
           try {
                 Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"); 
                 String myDatabase = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/project_app?user=root&password=1234"; 
                 Connection myConnection = DriverManager.getConnection(myDatabase);
                Statement myStatement = myConnection.createStatement();  
               String sqlString = "INSERT INTO dest(Country,City,URL) VALUES ('"+id8+"', '"+id9+"','"+id10+"')";
               String  insert= "INSERT INTO dest_has_categories(Categories_idCategories) VALUES ('"+ch1+"')";

             try{
                            myStatement.executeUpdate(sqlString);
                            myStatement.executeUpdate(insert);                        

                        }catch(SQLException sqlException) { 
            %>       

            <%
                            flag = true;
                        }
                        if(flag == false ){



                        }

                        // Close the connection to the database
                        myStatement.close();
                        myConnection.close();
                   }catch(Exception e){
                         e.printStackTrace();  
                   } 
                }else{        
            %>

            <%
                }
            %>
```

PS: there are two different tables for inserts as you can see...

html page :

```
  <form name="createdest" method="get" action="../jsp/create-dest-code.jsp">
        Country: <input type="text"  required  name="id8" /> <br>
        City: <input type="text"  required  name="id9" /> <br>
        URL Video: <input type="url"  required  name="id10" /> <br> <br>
        <i><ins>Categorize the destination (max 2): </ins></i>  <br> <br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="dest1" value="2" onClick="return KeepCount()" >Christmas<br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="dest2" value="1" onClick="return KeepCount()" >Winter <br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="dest3" value="3" onClick="return KeepCount()" >Summer <br> <br>

        <input type="submit" class="button" value="CREATE DESTINATION" /> 


        <br>


        </form>
       <SCRIPT LANGUAGE="javascript">

function KeepCount() {

var NewCount = 0;

if (document.createdest.dest1.checked)
{NewCount = NewCount + 1;}

if (document.createdest.dest2.checked)
{NewCount = NewCount + 1;}

if (document.createdest.dest3.checked)
{NewCount = NewCount + 1;}

if (NewCount == 3)
{
alert('Pick Just Two Please');
document.createdest; return false;
}
} 
</SCRIPT>
```

mysql tables :

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `project_app`.`Dest` (
  `idDest` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Country` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `City` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `URL` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idDest`))
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `project_app`.`Categories` (
  `idCategories` INT NOT NULL,
  `Categories` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idCategories`))
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `project_app`.`Dest_has_Categories` (
  `Dest_idDest` INT NOT NULL ,
  `Categories_idCategories` INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Dest_idDest`, `Categories_idCategories`),
  INDEX `fk_Dest_has_Categories_Categories1_idx` (`Categories_idCategories` ASC),
  INDEX `fk_Dest_has_Categories_Dest_idx` (`Dest_idDest` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_Dest_has_Categories_Dest`
    FOREIGN KEY (`Dest_idDest`)
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`Dest` (`idDest`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_Dest_has_Categories_Categories1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`Categories_idCategories`)
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`Categories` (`idCategories`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
INSERT INTO categories(idCategories,Categories) VALUES (1,'Winter');
INSERT INTO categories(idCategories,Categories) VALUES (2,'Christmas');
INSERT INTO categories(idCategories,Categories) VALUES (3,'Summer');
```

Comment: It's a really bad practice to include your java code inside your jsp page

Comment: i know but my exersice says it...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Solution 1

Create two different Statement instances for your two insert operations.

### Solution 2

If you want to reuse one single Statement instance, close the resources in a **Finally** block. Actually it is always a good idea to put the close statement in **finally** block or simply use **try-catch-resource** that jdk7+ has to offer.

### Unrelated to your concrete questions

- It is highly recommended that you avoid using java code in jsp file. Search the terms "jsp servlet mvc".
- Use PreparedStatement instead of Statement to avoid sql injection attack.

#### EDIT for solution 1:

In your first try block:
Under  `Statement myStatement = myConnection.createStatement();`
add  `Statement myStatementTwo = myConnection.createStatement();`

In your second try block:
change `myStatement.executeUpdate(sqlString);`
to `myStatementTwo.executeUpdate(sqlString);`

Add a final block for your first try block and close all your resource there. Editing your code is pretty much the same as rewriting everything from scratch, it is going to benefit you most if you can do that yourself.

#### EDIT after OP provided HTML code and database

Your **Dest_has_Categories** table's **Dest_idDest** is an **auto_increment** column but it is also a foreign key referencing **Dest**'s primary key **idDest**. Reference Table (joint table) 's foreign keys **should not** be auto_increment. There will be problems if the auto incremented value generated by DBMS does not exist in the referencing table.

Please make the foreign keys not auto_increment and when you insert to the reference table **Dest_has_Categories**, please insert existing **Categories**'s id and **Dest**'s id.

Also, when you change your code, make sure to also use my Solution 2 for best practice.

Comment: it doesnt work... but let me be more specific, if you can see from my edit , my tables and my html page... i need to take data from users form and save them to database, but here is the point... in checkboxes user can check two and less... so can you help me if the tables and formation of them is right and if its right what can i do in order to take the two values of checkbox and insert them in one table...

Comment: @JohnV  Your **Dest_has_Categories** table's **Dest_idDest** is an **auto_increment** column but it is also a **foreign key** referencing **Dest**'s primary key **idDest**. Reference Table (joint table) 's foreign keys **should not** be auto_increment. There will be problems if the auto incremented value generated by dbms does not exist in the referencing table. When the insert operations do not work, are there any exceptions? If yes, could you please also provide us with the stacktrace?

Comment: yea wrong i edited now... thats the problem i have to insert user checkbox somewhere i mean dest_id from dest is auto_increment and category id its already inserted but i need now the values of checkboxes in the Dest_has_categories  with the right match  of dest id and the right match of category id i mean user to give : country : spain city:madrid url: ....  and check the winter checkbox  , with this code i am inserting the country,city,url in the dest table  but the value of checkbox nowere...